# Recursive behavior

Tags: python, function, recursion, stack

Why does the following executes such that the `print` statement is called as often as it recursed but the count variable, `count`, when `x == 1` is never reached.

```
def count_bits(n, count = 0):
  x = n % 2
  if n == 1:
    return count + 1
  
  if n < 1:
    return count

  if x == 1:
    count += 1 # when x == 1
  
  count_bits(int(n/2), count)
  print("counter")

  return count
```

> why is it necessary to recurse with the `return` statement?  Because if the recursive call is above the `return` statement the code
> returns the wrong output but with the recursive call called with
> `return` keyword, everything works well.  Typically, the `print` statement
> prints 'counter' as often as it recursed showing that the recursive call
> works.

On the other hand, if "return" follows after the recursive call, it returns the count from the base condition, correctly.

```
def count_bits(n, count = 0):
  x = n % 2
  if n == 1:
    return count + 1
  
  if n < 1:
    return count

  if x == 1:
    count += 1

  return count_bits(int(n/2), count)
```

Comment: "On the other hand, if "return" follows after the recursive call, it returns the count from the base condition, correctly." Yes; this is for the same reason that you would have to do the same thing to get the same effect if you were calling *any other function* instead of making a recursive call. Recursion is *not special*; it is *just* calling a function that *happens* to be implemented with the same code. When you call a function, if you want to use the value that was returned, you have to actually use it. If you want to return the value that you got from that call, then use `return`.

Comment: To be clear: each time you call the function recursively is a *separate process* with a *completely independent set* of local variables. The value of `count` is **not** shared in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return recursion result, as reccurent function meaning is `to count current step you have to get result of previous step`

```
F_k = F_k-1 * a + b  # simple example
```

Means that you have to get result of `F_k-1` from F_k and count current result using it.

Answer (score 0):

I advised you to use `snoop` package to debug your code more efficient , by this package you can track the executing step by step.
to install it run:

`Pip install snoop`

`Import snoop`

add snoop decorator to count_bits()

for about the package see this link
https://pypi.org/project/snoop/

Answer (score 0):

the difference in the output between the two methods is because of the way in which python handles fundamental data types. Fundamental data types such as float, ints, strings etc are passed *by value*, whereas complex data types such as dict, list, tuple etc are passed *by reference*. changes made to fundamental data types within a function will therefore only be changed within the local scope of the function, however changes made to a complex data type will change the original object. See below for an example:

```py
x = 5

def test_sum(i : int):
  print(i)
  i += 5
  print(i)

# the integer value in the global scope is not changed, changes in test_sum() are only applied within the function scope
test_sum(x)
print(x)

y = [1,2,3,4]

def test_append(l : list):
  print(l)
  l.append(10)
  print(l)

# the list in the global scope has '10' appended after being passed to test_append by reference
test_append(y)
print(y)
```

This happens because it's far cheaper computationally to pass a reference to a large object in memory than to copy it into the local scope of the function. For more information on the difference, there are thousands of resources available by searching "what is the difference between by reference and by value in programming".

As for your code, it seems to me the only difference is you should alter your first snippet as follows:

```py
def count_bits(n, count = 0):
  x = n % 2
  if n == 1:
    return count + 1
  
  if n < 1:
    return count

  if x == 1:
    count += 1 # when x == 1
  
  # assign the returned count to the count variable in this function scope
  count = count_bits(int(n/2), count)
  print("counter")

  return count
```

The second code snippet you wrote is almost identical, it just doesn't assign the new value to the 'count' variable. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Actually, the expectation was that the count variable keeps track of its value and its reused in the function call so the execution of the base case should return its most recent value.
Thanks

Comment: It is still not cleared because if you include
`print(count)`
above the `count_bits(int(n/2), count)`
you get the count value proper which means it counts well so what has changed in the base condition?

Comment: `count=count(int(n/2), count)`

`return count`
is similar to

`return count(int(n/2), count)`